# Finding the encryption key for a cipher given the plaintext and the ciphertext

Tags: cryptography

The given cipher text is this:

CWT VIFTDBOTBC NDINIAMRA GTDT DTYTQCTS PK CWT RMPIED ANIZTAOMB MA XDDTRTFMBC CI CWT NDIPRTOA CWMC CWT RXPDMDK ATDFXQT XA UMQXBV

Using frequency analysis and some trial and error I have the plaintext:

THE GOVERNMENT PROPOSALS WERE REJECTED BY THE LABOUR SPOKESMAN AS IRRELEVANT TO THE PROBLEMS THAT THE LIBRARY SERVICE IS FACING

I have been told that this ciphertext has been obtained using a mono-alphabetic (substitution) cipher that is not an affine cipher. However I can't seem to find the key, I have tried using a 2-by-2 hill cipher and a Caesar Cipher but neither work. There is no common link I can find between the plain text alphabet and the Cipher text alphabet below:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p r s t u v w y 
m p q s t u v w x y z r o b i n d a c e f g k
```

where q,x,z have no known ciphertext encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cipher alphabet seems to be based on the keyword "robin hood" then q would map to h ,and we remove letters we already used (so the double o disappears), where you start half-way the alphabet (a bit non-standard) at l, and go circular. After the keyword letters are used up you start at the start of the alphabet (that is the acefg part). So x would map to j, q to h, z to l.

For the keyword idea, [also see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). This is quite standard, though not very good, as the permutations tend to get recognisable sequences in alphabetic order ,which can be abused for solving them.

Comment: I would suggest considering "start at L" to be part of the key. It's not exactly halway anyway.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sure, "robin hood" and "start at l" would be a (the) way to rederive the full permutation key.